# How to create a markup menu in telegrambot

Tags: python, user-interface, menu, bots, telegram-bot

I'm trying to create a telegram bot with menu using `Update` class. I would combine `InlineMenuKeyboard` with `ReplyKeyboardMarkup`.

I created  one bot using annotations and it's working well with both kinds of menu. But I don't like this structure.

But here `inlineKeyboard` is working well, `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` isn't displayed.
I`m not expert in creating bots that's why I will be glad if anybody would send me some examples of bots with correct architecture and structure?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telebot import types
############################### Bot ############################################

def start(bot, update):

    update.message.reply_text(main_menu_message(),
                            reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())

def test(bot,update):
    print("TEST")
    markup_settings_menu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup_settings_menu.add(types.KeyboardButton('Change name'),
                             types.KeyboardButton('Change Phone number'),
                             types.KeyboardButton('it`s a test')
    print("test 1.5")
    update.message.reply_text('hELLO',
                              reply_markup=markup_settings_menu)
    print("TEST2")

def create_settings_menu():
    markup_settings_menu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup_settings_menu.add(types.KeyboardButton('Change name'),
                             types.KeyboardButton('Change Phone number'),
                             types.KeyboardButton(cs.home_emoji))
    return markup_settings_menu


def main_menu(bot, update):
  query = update.callback_query
  bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=query.message.message_id,
                        text=main_menu_message(),
                        reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())

def first_menu(bot, update):
  query = update.callback_query
  bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=query.message.message_id,
                        text=first_menu_message(),
                        reply_markup=first_menu_keyboard())

def second_menu(bot, update):
  query = update.callback_query
  bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=query.message.message_id,
                        text=second_menu_message(),
                        reply_markup=second_menu_keyboard())

# and so on for every callback_data option
def first_submenu(bot, update):
  pass

def second_submenu(bot, update):
  pass

############################ Keyboards #########################################
def main_menu_keyboard():
  keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Option 1', callback_data='m1')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Option 2', callback_data='m2')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Option 3', callback_data='m3')]]
  return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)


def first_menu_keyboard():
  keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Submenu 1-1', callback_data='m1_1')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Submenu 1-2', callback_data='m1_2')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Main menu', callback_data='main')]]
  return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

def second_menu_keyboard():
  keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Submenu 2-1', callback_data='m2_1')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Submenu 2-2', callback_data='m2_2')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Main menu', callback_data='main')]]
  return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)


def create_markup_menu():
    markup_menu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
    markup_menu.add(types.KeyboardButton('Order room'),
                    types.KeyboardButton('Manage order'),
                    types.KeyboardButton('Orders history'),
                    types.KeyboardButton('⚙️Settings'),
                    types.KeyboardButton('❓Help'))
    return InlineKeyboardButton(markup_menu)

#===============================================================================

############################# Messages #########################################
def main_menu_message():
  return 'Choose the option in main menu:1111'

def first_menu_message():
  return 'Choose the submenu in first menu:'

def second_menu_message():
  return 'Choose the submenu in second menu:'

############################# Handlers #########################################
updater = Updater('===TOKEN===')

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('test', test))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(main_menu, pattern='main'))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(first_menu, pattern='m1'))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(second_menu, pattern='m2'))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(first_submenu,
                                                    pattern='m1_1'))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(second_submenu,
                                                    pattern='m2_1'))

updater.start_polling()
################################################################################
```